# How to access a corresponding object's value according to the click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is the sample in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nba_jl/vfedLwfm/27/)

```
<a href="#"></a>
<a href="#"></a>
<a href="#"></a>
<a href="#"></a>
<div></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function Produit(nom, prix){
    this.nom = nom;
    this.prix = prix;
};

var apple = new Produit("apple", 0.30);
var banana = new Produit("banana", 0.03);
var pear = new Produit("pear", 0.35);
var kiwi = new Produit("kiwi", 0.40);

var produit = [apple,banana,pear,kiwi];

for(var i = 0; i < produit.length; i++){
    $('a').eq(i).html(produit[i].nom + '<br/>');
};

$('a').click(function(){
    var quantity = 0;
    quantity++;
    $('div').append(produit[0].nom + ' x ' + quantity + '<br/>');
});
```

So in the browser, we have four fruits. What I want is:

1. when I click a fruit, it will shows it's name and the quantity,
2. if I click on apple 2 times, it will shows 'apple x 2',
3. then if I click on kiwi, it will shows 'kiwi x 1' under 'apple x 2'
   As I don't know how to do that, in my code, I just put the 0 index of the table, to show you what it looks like.

What I know is:
- For 1, I need a `this` to replace the `0` in the `produit[ ]`, but I don't know how to apply `this`.
- For 2, I need a counter and an `if/else`, to compare that, once a fruit is clicked, the second click on it will increase the quantity, not append a new `<div>`.
- For 3, it will be in the `else` with #2, when the fruit is not match up, do `append`.

Comment: There are many non english country user in stack overflow, and of course we are not writers to perfect our text, so if every time an editer like this one can show up and correct it, that's cool !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to write the results to an array, then rewrite the div contents.  Use `.html()` instead of `.append()`

```js
function Produit(nom, prix){
    this.nom = nom;
    this.prix = prix;
};

var apple = new Produit("apple", 0.30);
var banana = new Produit("banana", 0.03);
var pear = new Produit("pear", 0.35);
var kiwi = new Produit("kiwi", 0.40);

var produit = [apple,banana,pear,kiwi];

for(var i = 0; i < produit.length; i++){
    $('a').eq(i).html(produit[i].nom + '<br/>');
};

a = {};
a.nameArray = [];
a.valueArray = [];
myString = "";

$('a').click(function(){
  var itemClicked = this.innerHTML.replace("<br>","");

  //if the nameArray does NOT contain the product, add it, and set value to 1.  If it does contain the product, increment value by 1.
  if(a.nameArray.indexOf(itemClicked)==-1){
    a.nameArray.push(itemClicked);
    a.valueArray.push(1);
  } else {
    a.valueArray[a.nameArray.indexOf(itemClicked)] += 1;
  }

  //write the string based on contents of arrays
  myString = "";
  for(var i=0; i<a.nameArray.length;i++){
    myString += a.nameArray[i] + " x " + a.valueArray[i] + "<br/>";
  }

  //Rewrite the contents of the html div.
    $('div').html(myString);
});
```

```html
<a href="#"></a>
<a href="#"></a>
<a href="#"></a>
<a href="#"></a>
<div></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/s02ch9mt/1/

Comment: BlueRaven gave me the best answer, so I took it, but still thanks for your help.

Comment: Your methode is good too, rewrite the html with the check, I need more time to compare BlueRaven's and your's.

Comment: I tried your code too, I write the same way as yours, but, when I click on 'apple', it shows 'apple x 1', click on apple again, it shows 'apple x 2' under 'apple x 1', and the third click on 'apple', it continuts to append 'apple x 3' under 2 and 1, then I click on 'kiwi', it shows 'kiwi x 1' under a new 'apple x 3', click 'kiwi' again,  it continuts to append 'apple x 3' and 'kiwi x 2' under 'apple x 3' and 'kiwi x 1', seems it's doing append, but in your code, the string will overwrite and just add 1 to the nimber, du you have any idea why this happen?

Comment: I put my code based on yours in [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nba_jl/z0b8xmwa/9/), almost the same code, but my code just don't works as yours, can't figure out.

Comment: You're one character away from the right answer.  Change: `myString += a.nameArray[i] + " x " + a.valueArray[i] + "<br/>";` to `myString = a.nameArray[i] + " x " + a.valueArray[i] + "<br/>";` (Notice the = instead of +=).  The reason is, we need to clear the string each time, or it writes the last iteration's data too.

Comment: Still not working. I changed the '+=' to '=', in this case, when I click on the second fruit, it will replace the first one I've already clicked, and if I click the first one again, it dose nothing. Did you find something different between your code and mine?

Comment: I just compare line by line, and I found it!!! It's the variable **myString=" "**, I saw you created it ouside the click, so I did not write it again inside the click before the 'for', and that is the problem, I put it inside the click, and it works as yours!!! I don't understand why, but with or without this variable in the right place,  it's so important and different. Could you understand why? And thanks for you continuous help!

Comment: You are using the `+=` operator to APPEND data to `myString` each time a link is clicked.  If you do not use `myString = " "` to clear the myString variable of all previous data, then when a link is clicked the second time, the myString variable still contains the text "apple x 1".  Then "apple x 2" gets APPENDED to it (because of the +=).  That's causing the problem you noticed.  What you need is to REPLACE the contents of myString instead of APPEND to it.  You could use `=` instead of `+=`. Then you won't need to clear `myString` each time the function is called.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again, for the previous questiions, it's solved. I'm now coding based on your code, there are some new questions, I put my code on [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nba_jl/z0b8xmwa/128/), now I want 2 more button, 'minus' and 'delete', 'minus' to minus one from the quantity, 'delete' to remove the transaction. So far, I made both of them but not working well, 'minus' works when there's only one fruit, once it's more than one, it works on everybody and it's a chaos, I know that I need a `this` somewhere but I don't know how to do. And the 'delete' is worse, can't solve it.

Comment: And for the 'minus' button, how to stop it's function when the quantity remains one? I tried a `do...while` but not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110863/discussion-between-jiang-lan-and-timothy-kanski).

Answer (score 2):

I would simplify this problem slightly by adding a quantity to your Produit object and adding an ID to each link. You can use $(this).text() to access the text value of each link, but the ID will be more reliable and makes for simpler code. I'm not sure if you're concerned with the order the products show up in the list within your div... The solution below just iterates through your array of products and displays the quantities of all that are greater than 0.

```
function Produit(nom, prix, qty){
  this.nom = nom;
  this.prix = prix;
  this.qty = qty;
};

var apple = new Produit("apple", 0.30, 0);
var banana = new Produit("banana", 0.03, 0);
var pear = new Produit("pear", 0.35, 0);
var kiwi = new Produit("kiwi", 0.40, 0);

var produit = [apple,banana,pear,kiwi];

for(var i = 0; i < produit.length; i++){
  $('a').eq(i).html(produit[i].nom + '<br/>').attr("id","produit_"+i);
};

$('a').click(function(){
  var id = $(this).attr("id").replace("produit_","");
  produit[id].qty++;
  var div = '';
  for(var i = 0; i<produit.length; i++){
    if(produit[i].qty>0)
      div += produit[i].nom + ' x ' + produit[i].qty + '<br/>'
  }
  $('div').html(div);
});
```

If you simply want to append the current quantity of the item, you can do that like this:

```
$('a').click(function(){
  var id = $(this).attr("id").replace("produit_","");
  produit[id].qty++;
  $('div').append(produit[id].nom + ' x ' + produit[id].qty + '<br />')
});
```

Comment: Your methode is very good! I spent a long time to understand it, what you did is: 1. add the quantity in the class so everybody can access to it; 2. give an ID to each fruit, you call them 'produit_' + index because the ID name can't be only a number; 3. you store the index according to the click by get rid of the 'produit_' (that's so COOL!), now we have a dynamic increment; 4. you creat a var 'div' empty, then in a `for` loop, you do the 'a=a+b' when the quantity is more then 0; At last, you rewrite the div.

Comment: The only thing that I'm not clear is, when you do 'a=a+b', the number will increase, the different string will be showed in new line, but the same string will be overwrite? I don't know that

Comment: In fact, the order to show up the list is also improtant, for example this is the online shop, when I click randomly the product, the list should show up either append or repend, that's more logical, now with the index, the list order is already fixed, how to correct it to be append or prepend? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I exactly understand, but I edited my answer with what I think you're asking. Hopefully it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the [filter function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) like:

```js
function Produit(nom, prix){
  this.nom = nom;
  this.prix = prix;
  this.quantity = 0;
};

var apple = new Produit("apple", 0.30);
var banana = new Produit("banana", 0.03);
var pear = new Produit("pear", 0.35);
var kiwi = new Produit("kiwi", 0.40);

var produit = [apple,banana,pear,kiwi];

$(function () {
  for(var i = 0; i < produit.length; i++){
    $('a').eq(i).text(produit[i].nom).append('<br>');
    
    // create the elements and set visibility to none
    $('div').append('<p id="' + produit[i].nom + '" style="display:none;">' + produit[i].nom + ' x ' + produit[i].quantity + '</p>');
  };

  $('a').click(function(e){
    
    // get the selected fruit object from produit
    var objSelected = produit.filter(function(val, index) {
      return val.nom == e.target.textContent;
    });
    
     var para = $('#' + objSelected[0].nom);
     if (para.length == 1) {
       para.text(objSelected[0].nom + ' x ' + objSelected[0].quantity).toggle(true);
     }
     objSelected[0].quantity += 1;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>

<a href="#"></a>
<a href="#"></a>
<a href="#"></a>
<a href="#"></a>
<div></div>
```

Comment: BlueRaven gave me the best answer, so I took it, but still thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd add a "quantity" property to your Produit class and initialize it to zero.

```
    function Produit(nom, prix){
        this.nom = nom;
        this.prix = prix;
        this.qty = 0; 
    };
```

Now you can change THIS Produit's quantity with every click:

```
    $('a').click(function(){
    $('div').append(produit[0].nom + ' x ' + produit[0].qty + '<br/>');
    };
```

Let me know if this works for you!

-- Ada

Comment: BlueRaven gave me the best answer, so I took it, your idea is a part of his, so I believe it will work for me.

Answer (score 0):

you suppose to have a attribute for each element to have its own quantity count
and you can 'this' for current clicked element

use count attribute in anchor element for counting quantities
and your updated code here

```
<a href="#" count=0></a>
<a href="#" count=0></a>
<a href="#" count=0></a>
<a href="#" count=0></a>
<div></div>
```

and javascript:

```
function Produit(nom, prix){
  this.nom = nom;
  this.prix = prix;
};

var apple = new Produit("apple", 0.30);
var banana = new Produit("banana", 0.03);
var pear = new Produit("pear", 0.35);
var kiwi = new Produit("kiwi", 0.40);

var produit = [apple,banana,pear,kiwi];

for(var i = 0; i < produit.length; i++){
  $('a').eq(i).html(produit[i].nom + '<br/>');
};

$('a').click(function(){
  var currentElement = $(this);
  var quantity = currentElement.attr('count');
  quantity++;
  currentElement.attr('count',quantity);

  $('div').append(currentElement.text() + ' x ' + quantity + '<br/>');
});
```

[jSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vfedLwfm/31/)

Comment: BlueRaven gave me the best answer, so I took it, but still thanks for your help.